# Camel case regex not working

Tags: java, regex, regex-greedy

I am trying to find camel case element from a string,
ex : `iOS`

Below is what is trying :

```
token.matches("(a-z)+(//W)")
```

but it is not picking up camel case words.

Help will be appreciated thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the regex:

```
"[a-z]+[A-Z]+"
```

`(a-z)+` matches literal `a-z` one or more times and `(//W)` matches literal `//W` one time.

Square brackets are used for character ranges, not parentheses.

And if you meant `\\W`, this is equivalent to `[^\\w]`, meaning "not word characters". It will be matching stuff like punctuation and spaces.

Comment: @user2805482 No. `[(//W)]+` will match any of `(`, `)`, `/` or `W` one or more times. Why don't you want to use `[A-Z]+`?

Comment: @user2805482: To clarify, you *probably* meant `\W` which in a Java string (for lack of raw strings) means `\\W`. However, I'd strongly advise against using `\w`, `\W`, and `\b` because `\w` is ambiguously called »word character« but includes uppercase and lowercase letters as well as digits and the underscore. Unless that's exactly what you want (which is *very* rare) you probably shouldn't use them. Furthermore `\W` means »anything that's not a word character«; you're probably expecting it to mean »uppercase letter« which it doesn't.